# Add MySQL to a ROS project?

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

How would I add MySQL functionality to a ROS project? I am running Ubuntu 11.04, I have MySQL installed, the .h is located at /usr/include/mysql/mysql.h.

Is there a way to include MySQL in the CMakeLists.txt file? Ideally, I would like to be able to do something like: #include <mysql.h> from my node.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32520/add-mysql-to-a-ros-project?/) by [gavinmachine](https://answers.ros.org/users/1039/gavinmachine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 353 on 2012-04-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*This may not be complete:*

First, add `<rosdep name="libmysqlclient-dev"/>` to your `manifest.xml`.

Reference the file in your C++ sources using: `#include <mysql/mysql.h>`

Add something like this to your `CmakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(MySql REQUIRED)
include_directories(${MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${MYSQL_DEFINITIONS})
```

UPDATE: a library that depends on MySQL probably needs to export some link flags in its `manifest.xml` like this:

```
<export>
  <cpp lflags="-lmysqlclient"/>
</export>
```

Normally, that would be done using `pkg-config`, but I don't see a `.pc` file for MySQL on Ubuntu Oneiric. You may have to figure out the correct `lflags` experimentally.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gavinmachine](https://answers.ros.org/users/1039/gavinmachine/) on 2012-04-24**:
I think this is on the right track... To give more info: I am trying to execute MySQL queries in a package that I expose as a library to another node... the library package compiles just fine, it's when I try to compile the node that depends on the library that I get an error.

**Comment by [Dustin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1938/dustin/) on 2012-04-25**:
What is the error?

**Comment by [gavinmachine](https://answers.ros.org/users/1039/gavinmachine/) on 2012-04-26**:
Dustin, say for example I attempt to call a library function from within the C++ of the node that is using the library, and the library function uses mysql_init(...),  the compiler will throw "mysql_init(...) has not been defined." The library package itself compiles just fine, however.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-26**:
Did you find a set of export lflags to solve that problem? Is it the compiler or the linker complaining about an unresolved mysql_init()?

**Comment by [gavinmachine](https://answers.ros.org/users/1039/gavinmachine/) on 2012-05-03**:
Yep, adding the linker flag appeared to fix it! I added exactly what you posted above.